# how to check if the interstitial of Chartboost loaded? and otherwise use admob

Tags: android, eclipse, admob, interstitial, chartboost

I am beginner in android, and I'm wanting to put advertising. I wanted to know how to check if the interstitial of charboost is loaded. It is ok?:

```
Chartboost.cacheInterstitial(CBLocation.LOCATION_DEFAULT);
                if(Chartboost.hasInterstitial(CBLocation.LOCATION_DEFAULT)){
                    //displayInterstitial();
                    Chartboost.showInterstitial(CBLocation.LOCATION_DEFAULT);
                }else{
                    displayInterstitial();
                }
```

I think it works but do not want to screw up

Comment: have you read their documentation?

Comment: Yes, but I don't found on this subject. Anyway my English is not very good, maybe that's why, so consult.

Answer (score 0):

It is in [Chartboost Documentation](https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/204213159). see 'Caching' in Advanced Topics.

Android

```
if (Chartboost.hasInterstitial(CBLocation.LOCATION_HOME_SCREEN)) {
    Chartboost.showInterstitial(CBLocation.LOCATION_HOME_SCREEN);
}
else {
    Chartboost.cacheInterstitial(CBLocation.LOCATION_HOME_SCREEN);
}
```